# What is the proper way to use an access token returned by passport.js?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, passport.js, google-oauth

I'm trying to understand how to use oauth2 in a pet project. I understand how passport.js uses the middleware `passport.authenticate('google'...)` to make sure that a user is authorized and I understand that the access token, refresh token, and profile are returned. However, how would I use the access token properly? When I get the access token, then I know that a user has been successfully authenticated and I have the scope information which is in profile. But then I'm just confused as to what I would need the accesstoken for now that I have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/concepts/curl-example

Is helpful. I don't believe that passport.js will do it for us.

To further clarify for future: Just use the access token in a header and send it as an option to request.

```
const opt = {
  url: 'some/protected/api',
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
  },
};

request.get(opt, (err, response, body) => {
...
});
```